# Rest API Patch only 1 field at a time

Tags: javascript, rest, express

I'm working on an inline grid editor that calls an express rest api after a single value in the grid is updated.  So when a user changes a single field in the grid, I am calling a `PATCH` request to update the field.  However I can't figure out how to only update a single field.  When I try it tries to update them all and if there's no value it makes the value NULL in the database.  I want to only update a single field, and only the one passed into the API (it could be any of the fields).  Here's my method to patch:

```
// Update record based on TxnID
router.patch('/editablerecords/update', function (req, res) {
    let qb_TxnID = req.body.txnid
    let type = req.body.type;
    let margin = req.body.margin;



    if (!qb_TxnID) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide TxnID' });
    }

    connection.query("UPDATE pxeQuoteToClose SET ? WHERE qb_TxnID = '" + qb_TxnID + "'", { type, margin  }, function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error){
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null })); 
            //If there is error, we send the error in the error section with 500 status
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ error: false, data: results, message: 'Record updated.' }));
            //If there is no error, all is good and response is 200OK.
        }
    });
});
```

I will only be updating 1 field at a time, either `type` or `margin`, but not both (in this case) at the same time.  If I only send one of the fields, the other field becomes null.  I've tried to read up on the `connection.query()` method but can find no information and I don't understand how it builds the query, except that every `req.body.value` that is passed to it gets used to build the query.

I'm new to building this REST API and feel like I'm missing something simple.

EDIT: I'd like to add, I MAY want to update both fields, but I'd also like to update a single field at a time.  Thanks

Comment: I suppose I could make a route for each field like `example.com/api/v1/editablerecords/update/id/field1` and `example.com/api/v1/editablerecords/update/id/field2` but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html#section-2), the body of a `PATCH` call should not be the updated representation, but rather a set of instructions to apply to the resource.

> The PATCH method requests that a set of changes described in the
> request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-
> URI.  The set of changes is represented in a format called a "patch
> document" identified by a media type.

One good proposed standard for using `PATCH` with JSON can be found at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902. An example patch document using that standard would be:

```
   [
     { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" },
     { "op": "remove", "path": "/a/b/c" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] },
     { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 },
     { "op": "move", "from": "/a/b/c", "path": "/a/b/d" },
     { "op": "copy", "from": "/a/b/d", "path": "/a/b/e" }
   ]
```

Comment: Well now I'm twice as confused... I'll just use PUT and force every field to be updated even though they aren't changing.  Thanks for your input